# Html string convert into attributed string with \U00002028\n ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Html string get it from server I tried convert into attributed string.
using

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                        initWithData: [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                        options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding] }
                                        documentAttributes: nil
                                        error: nil
                                        ];
```

attribute string having \U00002028\n that causes display string got spacing and line breaking in text.How can be able to remove such thing.

Comment: try this NSString *string = [attributedString.string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];   this way to achieve the leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trim leading and trailing whitespaces from NSMutableAttributedString

```
NSString * _strAchievementMsg= @"  Hi Test the White space    ";

NSString * htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><div>%@</div></html>",_strAchievementMsg];

NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                        initWithData: [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                        options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding] }
                                        documentAttributes: nil
                                        error: nil
                                        ];
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
NSRange range           = [attString.string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];
while (range.length != 0 && range.location == 0)
{
    [attString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
    range = [attString.string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];
}

// Trim trailing whitespace and newlines.
range = [attString.string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet
                                          options:NSBackwardsSearch];
while (range.length != 0 && NSMaxRange(range) == attString.length)
{
    [attString replaceCharactersInRange:range
                             withString:@""];
    range = [attString.string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet
                                              options:NSBackwardsSearch];
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you have done in each while loop. just for more explaination it help the others.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string = [attributedString.string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Only strips the leading and trailing whitespace.

```
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
string = [components componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Comment: but I want attributed string still not simple string

Comment: Convert this to attributed string next.

Comment: @gap are able to trim the Nsattributestring to Nsstring

Comment: NSString *string = [attributedString.string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];   this way to achieve the leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: @RaviMalviya you can see this [NSHipster nscharacterset](http://nshipster.com/nscharacterset/) .

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7, UIKit added an initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error: method which can initialize an NSAtttributedString using HTML Please try this

```
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
                                 options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                           NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} 
                      documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```